# How to joing to jpegs without loading them in memory

Tags: java, memory, jpeg, lossless

I've read something about jpeg Lossless editing, with it is possible to rotate, crop and a few other things without the need to really load the full image into memory, is there by any means a way of joining two jpegs together using this kind of technique? I was thinking something like copying the MCUs, quantization tables and huffman tables from one image into the other, in another user's question someone told it could be done but didn't tell how, the person said it would need reprocessing the edge MCUs or something like that

Comment: maybe you should use, Memory mapped file.

Comment: "I've read something...",  "...in another user's question someone told it could be done..." and "...or something like that" are all really vague statements. Link what you read, link the other questions/answers, add some detail of how you plan to solve it, with what you have learned so far. :-)